# SQL CHECK CONSTRAINT VARCHAR

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

```
create table table1
(
  column1 varchar2(8)
  check constraint column1_ch check ........
);
```

How do I do a check for a data that the first 4 char is a specific set of alphabets while the last 4 is numbers? and as well as a range of values.

examples, data can be ABCD2121, ABCD1111.

range - ABCD0001 to ABCD9999

So 'ABCD' is fixed while the numbers are changing.

I've foudn online about using '[]" to define the numbers but i'm not able to integrate it into my constraint.

Thanks

Comment: Look into substring functions or use a regex if your flavor of SQL allows it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do this using a regular expression:

```
alter table table1
  add constraint chck_code check (regexp_like(column1, '(ABCD)[0-9]{4}') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check condition should be as follows:

```
(column1 LIKE 'ABCD[0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]')
```

***Edit:*** *Modified to use a set prefix vs. a range for the alpha characters.*

Here's a solution using Microsoft SQL Server that illistrates this:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(column1 varchar(8) check (column1 LIKE 'ABCD[0-9][0-9][0-9][1-9]'))

INSERT INTO @MyTable (column1)
       SELECT 'ABCD0000'
 UNION SELECT 'ABCD2121'
 UNION SELECT 'ABCD1111';

SELECT *
  FROM @MyTable;

INSERT INTO @MyTable (column1)
SELECT 'ABCD000A'; --<== Fails!

INSERT INTO @MyTable (column1)
SELECT 'ABCD221'; --<== Fails!
```

Comment: Oh, and also make sure that you won't be surprised by any [collation issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx) too.

Comment: But this will allow any 4-letter prefix - this is not what the OP wants.

Comment: LIKE does not support regular expression (at least not in standard SQL and definitely not in Oracle)

Comment: @FrankSchmitt You're right - I've updated the example to only allow the 'ABCD' prefix. [Your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13235461/1796930) does seem to be better than mine though.

Comment: After putting this constraint, it's succcessful. but i wasnt able to import data into the table. it violated the constraint which i tried. However i tried a_horse_with_no_name way and it was ok. i was able to import the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a fixed set of prefixes, use regexp_like and enumerate the prefix list:

```
alter table test_1 
add constraint chk_col1 check(regexp_like(column1, '(ABCD|EFGH)[0-9]{4}'));
```

This will allow ABCD and EFGH as prefixes, followed by exactly 4 digits.